# Spring Batch partitioner method

Tags: java, spring-batch

When Spring partitioner reads the database, for example, it needs to count the equipment status of each application running every day from the A database (an application is running on the device, this database will add a record), I have read a lot of spring tutorials only According to id to partition method, hope to inform